# Incorrect Dimensions error with the function MRM, in the package ecodist

Tags: r, dimensions

when using the MRM function in the package Ecodist, I get the following error:

```
Error in xj[i, , drop = FALSE] : incorrect number of dimensions
```

I get this error no matter what I do, I even get it with the example code in the documentation:

```
data(graze)

  # Abundance of this grass is related to forest cover but not location
  MRM(dist(LOAR10) ~ dist(sitelocation) + dist(forestpct), data=graze, nperm=10)
```

I don't know what's going on. I have tried other computers and get the same error, so it's not even confined to my machine (windows 10, fully updated).

Best,

Joe

Comment: This code works fine for me and I don't get any error.

Comment: Yeah, I asked my buddy to run it on his machine and it worked for him too, so this is a me problem... the worst kind of problem. I have narrowed it down to something to do with the spdep package, since it works when I don't load it.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to Torsten Biemann for pointing me at this. I don't check stackoverflow regularly, but you are always welcome to email me at the ecodist maintainer address or open an issue at https://github.com/phiala/ecodist

As pointed out above, the example works correctly in a clean R session, but fails if spdep is loaded. I haven't figured out the conflict yet, but the problem is in the implict coercion of distance object to vector within the mechanics of using a formula. If you do that explicitly, the command works properly. I'll work on a patch, which will first be at the github above, and sent to CRAN after testing.

```
# R --vanilla --no-save

library(ecodist)
data(graze)

# Works
set.seed(1234)
MRM(dist(LOAR10) ~ dist(sitelocation) + dist(forestpct), data=graze, nperm=10)


$coef
                   dist(LOAR10) pval
Int                   6.9372046  1.0
dist(sitelocation)   -0.4840631  0.6
dist(forestpct)       0.1456083  0.1

$r.squared
        R2       pval
0.04927212 0.10000000

$F.test
       F   F.pval
31.66549  0.10000


library(spdep)

# Fails
MRM(dist(LOAR10) ~ dist(sitelocation) + dist(forestpct), data=graze, nperm=10)


Error in xj[i, , drop = FALSE] : incorrect number of dimensions


# Explicit conversion to vector

graze.d <- with(graze, data.frame(LOAR10 = as.vector(dist(LOAR10)), sitelocation = as.vector(dist(sitelocation)), forestpct = as.vector(dist(forestpct))))

# Works
set.seed(1234)
MRM(LOAR10 ~ sitelocation + forestpct, data=graze.d, nperm=10)


$coef
                 LOAR10 pval
Int           6.9372046  1.0
sitelocation -0.4840631  0.6
forestpct     0.1456083  0.1

$r.squared
        R2       pval
0.04927212 0.10000000

$F.test
       F   F.pval
31.66549  0.10000
```

Comment: In case others run across this:
Peter Dalgaard tracked the problem to the proxy package (required by spdep), which currently creates a S3 method dim.dist() which overwrites the default behavior so that instead of dim(distobject) being NULL, it is instead c(n, n). That's what breaks the formula interface.
The maintainer of proxy says they will eventually move that, because it's caused problems in other places. Meanwhile I'll think on whether there's an easy way to patch ecodist in the meantime. Possibly specify my own dim.dist().

Comment: thanks for the clarifications! a note for those coming for other reason: same may happen when trying to use `mantel` (and thus all functions calling `mantel`, like `mgram`).  In the meantime @Phiala implemented the patch in the last version of her package (she gives more details here : https://github.com/phiala/ecodist/issues/5#issuecomment-1682814774)  thus, using `devtools::install_github("phiala/ecodist")` instead of the CRAN version of ecodist should solve the issue for now!